# Why are the South China Sea and East China Sea still referred to as "南シナ海 " and "東シナ海" when "シナ" is considered derogatory when referring to China?

Tags: words

If China is usually referred to as [中国]{ちゅうごく}, then why do the names for the seas still use the old Japanese name? Is there a reason?

Comment: https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%94%AF%E9%82%A3#%E5%AD%A6%E8%A1%93%E7%9A%84%E3%81%AA%E4%BD%BF%E7%94%A8

Answer (score 1):

The name *has* been changed: it used to be written fully in kanji as 東支那海, but the preferred name since the war has been the katakana version 東シナ海.

As for *why* it hasn't been changed further, one problem is the lack of an obvious alternative.

- China calls it simply 東海, which doesn't work not only because the "East Sea" is west of Japan, but because that term is already used by Japan's [東海]{とうかい} region.
- 東中国海 is occasionally seen, but it's a mouthful (2 extra mora) and has a lesser semantic overlap with the [中国]{ちゅうごく} region.
- 東中華海 suggests Taiwan/Republic of China (中華民国), which is again geographically off.

More generally, while 中国/中華 can substitute for 支那 in many cultural contexts like food, for geographic terms they're not a great fit, and hence シナ lingers on in a few other words like インドシナ.

The other reason is simple inertia and lack of political will. 支那 has not been used as a hate word for decades and increasingly few Chinese are aware that it ever was one.  The Chinese state doesn't really seem to care: you can find 東シナ海 in places like a [joint Japan/PRC press release by the Foreign Ministry](https://www.mofa.go.jp/mofaj/area/china/higashi_shina/press.html), which Chinese diplomats have clearly signed off on.